# Avoid text shift as it goes up in a column

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm making a website where you can send messages in two different columns (for two supposed users).
There is a footsteps system that is adding a `<br>` every second so you have messages going up as soon as they appears.
SO basically, every time you send a message, it is going up in the column you sent it until it diseapper at the top of the page.

**My issue is the following:**

Every time a user enter a message it makes all the other messages of the column shift (which is normal I assume) but the other person's column is not affected by this change so it makes a huge shift in the order of messages on screen if it's a big message.
I would like to know if this is possible to compensate that; because I've been trying a lot of things but nothing came to my mind and *since I'm still learning, I can't see too far haha...*

[image]

```js
let identifier = 1;
var maxSteps = 500;
var i = 0;
var nbOfSteps = 0;
var timer;

function incrementDoc() {
  nbOfSteps++;
  $("<div />", {
      "class": "maxSteps"
    })
    .css({})
    .append($("<p>" + nbOfSteps + " pas </p>"))
    .appendTo(".one")
      $(".pathL").append($("<br>"))
      $(".pathR").append($("<br>"))
      $(".pathL").animate({scrollTop: $(".pathL")[0].scrollHeight}, 500);
      $(".pathR").animate({scrollTop: $(".pathR")[0].scrollHeight}, 500);
  $(".maxSteps").prev().remove();

  if (++i >= maxSteps) {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}

$( document ).ready(function() {

 $(document).on("click", ".add", function() {
    maxSteps += 10;
    console.log(maxSteps);
  })

  timer = setInterval(incrementDoc, 1000);

    $('#mL').keyup(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
            
            event.preventDefault();
            var message = $('#mL').val()
            $(this).parent().parent().append(
                $("<p class='messInd'>" + message + "</p>").attr('id', identifier)
                );
            $('#mL').val("") // retourner à la valeur 0 de #m

                identifier++;
            var text = $(".pathL").find('#' + identifier);
        }
    });

        $('#mR').keyup(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
            
            event.preventDefault();
            var message = $('#mR').val()
            $(this).parent().parent().append(
                $("<p>" + message + "</p>").attr('id', identifier)
                );
            $('#mR').val("") // retourner à la valeur 0 de #m

                identifier++;
            var text = $(".pathR").find('#' + identifier);
        }
    });

});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #5a6c58;
}

.messInd { 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}

#messL, 
#messR{
    width: 24vw;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: pink;
}


.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 0px;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(100vh, auto);
    height: 100vh;
}


.pathL,
.pathR
{
    -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
    overflow: scroll;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ffdbf5;
}


.pathL {
    background: rgb(255,219,245);
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

.pathR {
    background: rgb(255,255,245);
    grid-column: 2 / 2;
}



 
.pathL::-webkit-scrollbar, 
.pathR::-webkit-scrollbar{ 
    display: none;  /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class ="wrapper">
        <div class="pathL" id="droite"> 
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      
              <div id="messL">
                  <input id="mL" autocomplete="off" name="name"/>
              </div> 
        </div> 
    
        <div class="pathR" id="droite"> 
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

              <div id="messR">
                  <input id="mR" autocomplete="off" name="name"/>
            </div> 
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer I have for now is :

```
            console.log($('#' + identifier).height());
            var compensate = $('#' + identifier).height();

            $(".pathL").append( // the oposite column
                $("<div class ='compensate'></div>").css('height', compensate)
                );
```

It's adding a div of the height of the message sent to the other column.

Works fine!